# Error: Data location must be "memory" for return parameter in function, but none was given

Tags: solidity

I am unable to solve the error mentioned below.
Error: Data location must be "memory" for return parameter in function, but none was given.
    function fromHex(string memory s) public pure returns(bytes)

Please help to solve the same.
Here is the code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
contract SampleContract
{
    function fromHexChar(uint c) public pure returns(uint)
    {
        if(byte(c) >= byte('0') && byte(c) <= byte('9')) 
        {
            return c - uint(byte('0'));
        }
        if(byte(c) >= byte('a') && byte(c) <= byte('f'))
        {
            return 10 + c - uint(byte('a'));
        }
        if(byte(c) >= byte('A') && byte(c) <= byte('F'))
        {
            return 10 + c - uint(byte('A'));
        }
    }

    function fromHex(string memory s) public pure returns(bytes) 
    {
        bytes memory ss = bytes(s);
        require(ss.length%2 == 0);

        bytes memory r = new bytes(ss.length/2);
        for(uint i=0; i<ss.length/2; ++i)
        {
            r[i] = byte(fromHexChar(uint(ss[2*i]))*16 +         
            fromHexChar(uint(ss[2*i+1])));
        }
        return r;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function fromHex(string memory s) public pure returns(bytes memory)
```

Comment: Change is causing few more errors of types conversion. like                                                 Error: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "uint256" to "bytes1".
        if(byte(c) >= byte('0') && byte(c) <= byte('9'))                                                       Error: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "bytes1" to "uint256".
            return c - uint(byte('0'));

Comment: These new errors are not caused by adding `memory` identifier, they only appear after resolving the first error. Are you sure about what these functions do? `fromHexChar` receives an `uint` and returns a `uint`, it's not like a correct type conversion.